# How to load a file and parse tags using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file which contains lots of tags like follows:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-1">
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="template-2">
</script>
```

I want to load the file and than load all the content inside the script tags in memory.

I am trying the below code but it's not working:

```
tpl = {
        // Hash of preloaded templates for the app
        templates : {},
        loadTemplates : function(name) {
            var that = this;
            $.get(name, function(data) {
                $(data).find('script').each(function (_, entry) {
                    that.templates[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).text();
                });
            });
        },

        // Get template by name from hash of preloaded templates
        get : function(name) {
            return this.templates[name];
        }
    };
```

Call is made like this:

```
tpl.loadTemplates('/templates/templates-home.html');
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Isn't requirejs helps?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it's not working? Show us an example of the template call you're making. Is `tpl.get` working? What's the content of `this.templates`?

Comment: Are these tags in the DOM or on a separate file on your server that isn't served with your html page ?

Comment: no these are in a separate file and not served with my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you seem like you're on the right track. The browser will load (but ignore) script tags marked with `type=text/template` and you can later select the contents of those tags and process them with javascript.

I think your problem is likely with the order of your procedure.

You haven't posted the javascript **that uses** your templates so I can only assume. I suspect your trying to `load` the templates before the document is ready, thus, the script tags aren't actually on the page when you `load` them. To fix, your can move your javascripts **below** the templates in the document OR execute your code in a `window.onLoad` handler.

**EDIT**

Okay, now I have a better idea of what you're trying to do. You still haven't told me what part of this is broken, but my gut tells me that this bit is the problem: `$(data).find('script')`. jQuery expects to be traversing the DOM. At this point in time, data is just a string returned from the server, it's not actually loaded in the DOM. So jQuery won't actually find ANY script tags. Try appending your result to the `body` before querying the DOM for `script` elements. Maybe something like this:

```
$('body').append(data);
$('script[type="text/template"]').each ...
```

I'm not really thrilled about that though. Can you just inject them into the page on the server side? Why do you need to delay the loading?

**EDIT 2**

If you don't want your script tags to be visible in the html document, then I suggest you don't use them. Instead you can have your template endpoint just return a bundle of javascript and evaluate it directly. Something like:

```
 $.get(name, function(data) {
     // data is a string that sets up your window.template variable
     eval(data);
 });
```

Comment: these are in a separate file and not served with my html

Comment: Actually previously they were injected only. Than you dont need this loading thing. But what i saw all my templates are visible and the logic and all the Server side DTO signatures are all visible. So i thought may be instead of making them visible just call them when needed.So if i again append them than it will make the same situation of injecting them. I hope u understood. Any suggeation you have...

Comment: You can't consider the client secure. So no matter what, if your templates are being used in the client there's a way to see the logic. That said, I'll edit my answer with one last option.